# library not found for -lPods- Error while running iOS Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swiftui

I am running .xcworkspace file on xcode and I am getting the following error:-

```
library not found for -lPods-
```

This is my Podfile:-

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target '' do
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

# Pods for 
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
  pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.5.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.5.0'
  pod 'Phone-Country-Code-and-Flags'
  pod 'ListPlaceholder'
  pod 'Shimmer'
  
end

target '' do
    pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
end
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks:)

Comment: soo What happened ? my answer is working for you ?

Comment: @zeytin Yes! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Build Active Architecture Only" = YES and run the `pod install`

[image]